# How to get id of a specific view in a listview item, to change it programmatically

Tags: android, listview, view

The `ListView` item is in a `.xml` file and I use a regular `SimpleAdapter` with my `ListView`.

Comment: Get the child of a listView using it's index : listView.getChildAt(index);

Comment: you can do adapter.getChildAtPosition(position) if you know the position else get the position through onItemClickListener of list view